# How to remove space below the semi-circle in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

As you can see, there is a huge empty space below the semi-circle. It seems that although I used `startAngle=-90` and `endAngle=90` to draw a semi-circle pie, but it still draws a whole circle but just hides the bottom half.

here is the code:http://jsfiddle.net/vv72ceug/17/

[Here is how it looks](http://g.hiphotos.baidu.com/image/pic/item/a71ea8d3fd1f413489aaa3fd261f95cad0c85e97.jpg)

Comment: @Ondkloss So soryy, I have no right to post an image, and post the image link. If you cannot see the pic, I am gonna change the link.

Comment: Can you please provide a JSFiddle?

Comment: @Ondkloss yep, a semi-circle, if you download and see it in ur PC, u'll find that there is a huge space below the semi-circle. I've no idea how to remove it.

Comment: @RocoCTZ http://jsfiddle.net/vv72ceug/17/ thx!

Comment: I see now. Thank you for clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you set the `startAngle` and `endAngle` so you display only half of it, the space for the other half is still reserved. You can achieve the result that you want by repositioning the center of the chart.

Try changing the center property from `center: ['50%', '75%']` to `center: ['50%', '90%']`. This way you move the chart down the page so you don't have the empty space underneath.

Have a look at this **[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vv72ceug/39/)**.

Comment: thx so much, I tried your way, but there will be a space upon the semi-circle. However, thx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Set your `size` parameter as width value, then you get rid of spacing.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/vv72ceug/40/

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate everyones answer but none of the above answers do the trick to completely remove the white space below the graph.

I have found a css trick which would do this for you.

imagine this is the container tag.

you need to apply the following css to get what you want:

```
div#container {margin-bottom: -45% !important;}
div#container > div {margin-bottom: -45% !important;}
div#container > div.highcharts-container > svg {margin-bottom: -45%; max-height: 50% !important;}
```

I hope this helps